# Tiny window in the corner of Windows - unidentified process

Tags: windows-10

I have this tiny little #@&*! at the bottom of my desktop. The one in the red circle. I tried Sysinternal Process explorer, AutoHotKey WinSpy to see what is causing it's presence and I couldn't find out - they do not see it.

I cannot close it, cannot restore it, though there is option viac right click to do both.

It is not causing any harm (not that I know of) but it's presence is driving me insane.

Is there a way to kill this without trying to kill everything? Or at least find out where it came from?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload it to VirusTotal to check if it is a malware?

Comment: I know nothing about it - I do not know what process it is, or anything. Maybe to clarify - it is not that file, but that window with a red crossmark on it - I will edit the image

Comment: Highly suspicious window, can you find the process in the task manager too see what it is?

Comment: After you find the process, open file location.

Comment: Nooo, I cannot. As you can see, if you look in the question statement - I tried to find the process not only via task manager, but also with advanced tools like process explorer or WinSpy. So yeah, if I find the process, rest is easy - I need help with finding out what the process is.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is going through your task manager, closing things until it vanishes. You might want to make sure the "Image path name" and "Command line" columns are shown so you can see what you're removing before you do it.

Comment: Yeah, well, the question is saying "without trying to kill everything". I know I would find out this way, but I do not want to go this road. Reasons unspecified.